# Merge the output of two greps into one file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, command-prompt

So I have the following two commands:

```
grep 'substring1' file1.txt > outfile.txt
grep 'substring2' file2.txt > outfile.txt
```

I would like to merge the two greps together, and write them all to outfile.txt as one command. How would such command look like?

Comment: Use the append operator for the 2nd `grep` command `>>` in place of `>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily combine both commands in a row, like:

```
grep 'substring1' file1.txt > outfile.txt ; grep 'substring2' file2.txt >> outfile.txt
```

The ";" separate both commands, the second command will be executed after the first has finished.

The ">>" means you append the output to the already existing file. (if the file does not exists, there will be no difference to ">")

You can use this simple pattern for many different tasks.

Comment: Sorry, why is there a double >> in the second case, what does it mean exactly? Thanks

Comment: it means append to file instead of write new (i will adjust my answer)

Comment: Please check my edits of the original question. Will your solution work if the source files are different?

Comment: i have adjusted my answer. yes it works. in general both commands can be complete different and the pattern will work.

Comment: Note that `&&` makes the running of the second grep conditional on the exit code of the first grep.  You probably want `;` instead.

Comment: @John1024, I guess it's better to break up for this use case. As far as I understand the question, the user wants to get a merge result. If the first command fails, it's already clear that this merge result can't be calculated. So you can save the effort for the second command.

Comment: @snap From grep, a non-zero exit code does not mean that the command "failed."  It means that no matches were found.  There doesn't seem to be any reason to think that the OP doesn't want to grep the second file just because the first had no matches.

Comment: @John1024, oh that's really a good point ;). I don't was aware of this. I will adjust my answer, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Two possibilities:

- Group them:

  ```
  {
      grep 'substring1' file1.txt
      grep 'substring2' file2.txt
  } > outfile.txt
  ```

  or inline as:

  ```
  { grep 'substring1' file1.txt; grep 'substring2' file2.txt; } > outfile.txt
  ```

  (note the semicolon before the closing curly bracket).
- Use the [appending redirection operator `>>`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Appending-Redirected-Output) for the second redirection:

  ```
  grep 'substring1' file1.txt > outfile.txt
  grep 'substring2' file2.txt >> outfile.txt
  ```

The grouping method is preferable considering that the file will be opened only once. The second method is preferable if you need to do some stuff that will write to stdout between the two `grep`s.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first off, the way you have listed those commands, they will not finish. You have not provided a file name, so, grep will use stdin, and unless you give it some input, it will block.

Having said that, how about just doing it all in one command?

```
egrep 'substring1|substring2' source_file.txt > outfile.txt
```

`egrep` allows for matching multiple search strings, delimited by '|'.

Comment: Very good.  As a minor detail, as per the manpage, `egrep` has been deprecated in favor of the clumsier `grep -E`

Comment: Please see my edits. The trick is, the source files are different.

Comment: Note that this is different from what the OP asked for: the order of the `grep`'d lines might be different with your version.

Comment: @BaronYugovich That's an important detail that should have been part of the original question!

Comment: I apologize, my bad.